# Call to google map autocomplete service only when user finish typing

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I got 'normal' autocomplete working with google map perfectly on my site, but I only want to make a call to google when user has finish typing his query.

Requirement: only after user hit search, do I ask google for the address predictions. Once replied, I will show in UI the addresses separated into different components.

I got it working by using

```
 var service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
 service.getPlacePredictions()
```

I was able to get the predictions, however unlike with 'normal' autocomplete where I can use `getplaces()` and get different components of the address, i.e. (postal code, country, street number, route etc), `getPlacesPredictions()` only give  back an array. The problem with this array is that the number of elements is inconsistent, sometimes streetNumber and route are under same element, sometimes separate.

Comment: You have a place ID in each element of predictions array, so PlacesService.getDetails() for place ID should return all address components available for the given place.